# Data does not update in UI without Reload

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have to update a quantity of product. I have update the data in database using put request but in UI the page need to reload to see the updated value. Here is my code

```
 const ItemDetail = () => {
const { itemId } = useParams();
const [item, setItem] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    const url = `https://ancient-garden-83535.herokuapp.com/item/${itemId}`;


    fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setItem(data));
}, [])

//handle qantity deliver item 

const handleDeliverd = () => {
    const oldQuantity = parseInt(item.quantity)
    const quantity = oldQuantity - 1;
    const updatedQuantity = { quantity };


    //send data to  server

    const url = `https://ancient-garden-83535.herokuapp.com/item/${itemId}`;
    fetch(url, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(updatedQuantity)

    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);

        })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `setItem` to cause a render. React components automatically re-render whenever there is a change in their state or props

```
const handleDeliverd = () => {
    const oldQuantity = parseInt(item.quantity)
    const quantity = oldQuantity - 1;
    const updatedQuantity = { quantity };


    //send data to  server

    const url = `https://ancient-garden-83535.herokuapp.com/item/${itemId}`;
    fetch(url, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(updatedQuantity)

    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
            // console.log(result);
            setItem(result) // added setItems 

        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an auxiliary function fetchData and use it in useEffect to fetch data first time and after putting new data.

```
 const ItemDetail = () => {
 const { itemId } = useParams();
 const [item, setItem] = useState({});

 const fetchData = () => {
   const url = `https://ancient-garden-83535.herokuapp.com/item/${itemId}`;

   fetch(url)
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(data => setItem(data));
   }, [])
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [])


 const handleDeliverd = () => {
   const oldQuantity = parseInt(item.quantity)
   const quantity = oldQuantity - 1;
   const updatedQuantity = { quantity };

   const url = `https://ancient-garden-83535.herokuapp.com/item/${itemId}`;
   fetch(url, {
     method: "PUT",
     headers: {
       'content-type': 'application/json'
     },
     body: JSON.stringify(updatedQuantity)
   })
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(result => { console.log(result) })
     .then(fetchData)
 }
```